# Accessing non-static grid element in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I've got a page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="VKClient.ConversationListPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">            
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

and an element on it:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
```

I want to change content of ContentPanel from the outside of the class. The problem is that it's a non-static field and I can't access it without an instance of ConversationListPage class. I haven't found the way neither to access this instance(which is stored somewhere I'm sure) nor to make the field static. Are there methods to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. In a constructor of ConversationListPage I'm passing instance of it to another class():

```
public ConversationListPage()
{
    //Change "OuterClass" to an actual class name where you'll be passing the instance
    InitializeComponent();
    OuterClass.setConversationListPage(this);
}
```

And in OuterClass I have:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    private static ConversationListPage conversationListPage;

    public static void setConversationListPage(ConversationListPage page)
    {
        conversationListPage = page;
    }
}
```

And so you'll be able to access anything in ConversationListPage via conversationListPage field.